# Show hide elements on anchor click in a different container

Tags: jquery

I need to show a bunch of different flash banners. best I can figure is to hide them all, then show when the title is clicked

```
<!-- list that holds links -->
<ul id="bannerList" class="list">
    <li>Type
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Flash banner1 120x600</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Other Type
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Flash banner2 120x600</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="bannerTarget">
    <div class="vert">alpha</div>
    <div class="horiz">one</div>
    <div class="horiz">two</div>
    <div class="horiz">three</div>
    <div class="horiz">four</div>
</div>

#bannerTarget .vert {
width: 120px;
height: 600px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
display: none;
}

#bannerTarget .horiz {
width: 728px;
height: 90px;
margin: 0 auto;
float: left;
display: none;
}
```

I dont want to write a click function for each link to show it's corresponding div, how would I make the function more utilitarian? I'm having issues connecting a link to it's appropriate div

```
$("ul#bannerList li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $parent.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    $href.css("display","block");
});
```

This doesn't work...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a common naming convention for the `div` and the links like so:

```
<ul id="bannerList" class="list">
    <li>Type
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="link-1">Flash banner1 120x600</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li>Other Type
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" id="link-2">Flash banner2 120x600</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="bannerTarget">
    <div class="vert" id="div-1">alpha</div>
    <div class="horiz" id="div-2">one</div>
    <div class="horiz" id="div-3">two</div>
    <div class="horiz" id="div-4">three</div>
    <div class="horiz" id="div-5">four</div>
</div>
```

Your code then becomes:

```
$("ul#bannerList li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#bannerTarget > div').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('link-','');
    $('#div-'+id).show();
});
```

You can also achieve the same without using ID's but you'll need to keep the link order and the div order the same:

```
$("ul#bannerList li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#bannerTarget > div').hide();
    var link_index = $(this).parent().index();
    $('#bannerTarget > div').each(function(){
        if( $(this).index() == link_index ){
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: almost. It shows the first one (title) I click but doesn't change them when I click a second title. that is, it doesn't hide the visible one and show the one I clicked. Also, using your second method, and having two titles (li's) and two div's either one I click shows the first banner.

Comment: man thats brilliant (first one) works like a charm. I apologize if my question was unclear, but you seemed to understand it exactly. I really appreciate the help. So I can understand it and not just copy and paste it, you're saying 1) hide all children of the div bannerTarget (got that) 2) take the link's id and replace it with "link-" and the number after the dash? then match the div with the same id and show it?

Comment: Correctamundo. That way you can maintain a consistency between the links and the divs without having to rewrite individual JS code for each link. You only need to maintain a common naming convention. I'll fix my second solution in a bit as using the `index()` allows you to avoid ID's and classes as well.

Comment: I added this outside the click statement so the first one is visible $('#bannerTarget > div:not(:first-child)').hide();

Comment: You can even set it in your CSS so that you're not increasing the amount of JS being used. So in your CSS you can set `#bannerTarget > div{ display:none; }, #bannerTarget > div:first-child{ display:block; }`

Comment: yeah im testing to see which one loads quicker now, good point!

Comment: I've modified the second solution as well. Just note that the index starts at 0 and not 1. So if you need to start at 1, modify the lines -  `var link_index = $(this).parent().index()` and `if( $(this).index() == link_index )` by adding the 1 to the index.