# How to get jQuery indexed list items ordered the right way

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code in which a list of title links when clicked on open the relevant article on the right hand side. The first article is shown by default and the other articles are hidden until the next title down is clicked. What I have is the default article showing like I want but the title links when clicked on show the articles in the wrong order.

```js
$(function codeAddress() {
  $('.posts-box').html($('.hidden-posts ul li div article:eq(' + $('.test-titles ul li div').index($(this).parent()) + ')').html());
  window.onload = codeAddress;

  $('a').click(function() {
    $('.posts-box').html($('.hidden-posts ul li div article:eq(' + $('.test-titles ul li div').index($(this).parent()) + ')').html());
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.site-main {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.half {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-main">
  <div class="half test-titles">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" title="Test post Two">Test post Three</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" title="Test post Two">Test post Two</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" title="Test post one">Test post one</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <a href="#" title="Hello world!">Hello world!</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden hidden-posts">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          <article>
            <header class="entry-header">
              <h2>Hello world!</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Ugh four dollar toast cray authentic single-origin coffee brooklyn put a bird on it, intelligentsia hashtag vaporware lumbersexual yuccie occupy. Church-key man bun biodiesel, shaman disrupt single-origin coffee meggings lyft leggings. Listicle
                street art tumblr twee heirloom, scenester whatever master cleanse viral la croix umami pickled typewriter affogato. Vaporware celiac fanny pack</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <article>
            <header class="entry-header">
              <h2>Test post one</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Direct trade YOLO chia art party authentic, tumeric pok pok vinyl iPhone +1 palo santo. Jean shorts pop-up banjo freegan, thundercats chambray mumblecore heirloom. Seitan 8-bit yr.</p>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <article>
            <header class="entry-header">
              <h2>Test post Two</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Put a bird on it tousled you probably haven&#8217;t heard of them intelligentsia affogato chia health goth. Taiyaki kickstarter pinterest, twee distillery listicle chartreuse gentrify iPhone literally photo booth leggings kale chips.</p>
            </div>
            <!-- .entry-content -->
          </article>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div>
          <article>
            <header class="entry-header">
              <h2>Test post Three</h2>
            </header>
            <div class="entry-content">
              <p>Tbh sriracha ramps taiyaki YOLO seitan hoodie farm-to-table cornhole waistcoat beard dreamcatcher godard affogato. Air plant stumptown you probably haven&#8217;t heard of them</p>
            </div>
            <!-- .entry-content -->
          </article>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="half">
    <article class="posts-box">
    </article>
  </div>
```

I know there's probably something I could do to make the JS a bit neater but I'd like to get it working properly first.

View on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/znxaatvd/27/).

Thanks

Comment: This could be useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187193/show-hide-elements-on-anchor-click-in-a-different-container)

Comment: You are using the `:eq()` selector to target which posts to show. This means that the order of the links will determine which post it will display. If you want a different mapping, use IDs or HTML5 data- attributes to "link" the correct post to the anchor elements.

Comment: Your links are not in the same order as your articles which is why your links aren't showing the correct article (as you are using their index to show the corresponding index article)

Comment: I would change it so you use the href attribute of the link (then it will be a bit more accesible if you have js turned off): https://jsfiddle.net/znxaatvd/29/

Comment: Thanks Pete, eventually this is going to be built in Wordpress, so I'm not sure how I would get the # and the name into the link?

Comment: Not sure - haven't used wordpress in ages, if you cannot change the link and add an id, just make sure the order of your articles match the order of your links and then your existing jquery will work correctly

Comment: Yea I started with the right order but it showed the content of the first post ('Hello World") instead of the top post, so I reversed the order in WP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use this function :

```
$(function codeAddress() {
    var postBox = $('.posts-box');
    var articleHeaders = $('.entry-header');
    function getPostContent(post){
        var content = '';
        articleHeaders.each(function(){
            var h1 = $(this).find('h2'); 
            if(post.html()==h1.html()){
                content = $(this).parent().html();
            }
        });
        postBox.html( content);
    }
    $('a').click(function() { 
        getPostContent($(this));       // get content by link title
    }); 
    getPostContent($('a').eq(0));      // if you want initial content
});
```

https://codepen.io/FaridNaderi/pen/WOMBaL

While its not the best way but hope it helps you with your code situation.